# For every integer $n\ge 0$ $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n-(-1)^n(x-1)^n}{x^n+(-1)^n(x-1)^n}dx=0$ Why?

Tags: integration

Can someone explain to me, why is this integral always has a zero answer?

n is an integer, $n\ge0$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n-(-1)^n(x-1)^n}{x^n+(-1)^n(x-1)^n}dx=0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$I:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n-(-1)^n(x-1)^n}{x^n+(-1)^n(x-1)^n}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n-(1-x)^n}{x^n+(1-x)^n}dx.$$
Use the substitution $t=1-x$ it is easy to see that
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-t)^n-t^n}{(1-t)^n+t^n}dx=-I.$$
Therefore $I=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint $f(x)=f(a+b-x)$ substitute $1-x$ in place of x in the original equation. Now add these two equations the denominator r remains constant but numerator adds up to $0$.